# jQuery effects not working after load more

Tags: jquery, css, drupal

I'm using Drupal 7 and get my content with View module on page. And my pager [Views Load More](http://drupal.org/project/views_load_more) module. And my thumbnail effect hover, shadow etc. Image hover using this code:

```
    var hoverImg = '<div class="hoverimg"></div>';

    $(".thumb").each(function(){
        $(this).children("div").each(function(){
            $(this).find("a").append(hoverImg);
        });
    });

    $(".thumb div").hover(function() {
        $(this).find(".hoverimg").animate({ opacity: 'toggle' });
    });

$(".thumb").hover(function() {
    $(this).find("div").each(function(){
        $(this).find(".shadow").fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

And getting number on my current thumbnail. This code:

```
var c = '';
var d = '';
$('.view-content div.views-row').each(function(){
    c = 0;
    d = 0;
    var i = 1;
    d = $(this).find('.thumbimg').length;
    $(this).find('.thumbimg').each(function(){
        sayi=i++;
        $(this).append('<div class="img_no">0'+sayi+'</div>');
    });
});
```

Everything is OK. All effects on start page. But when click Load More button, my effects can't work another page.

My Views Load More js code:

```
/**
 * @file views_load_more.js
 *
 * Handles the AJAX pager for the view_load_more plugin.
 */
(function ($) {

  /**
   * Provide a series of commands that the server can request the client perform.
   */
  Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.viewsLoadMoreAppend = function (ajax, response, status) {
    // Get information from the response. If it is not there, default to
    // our presets.
    var wrapper = response.selector ? $(response.selector) : $(ajax.wrapper);
    var method = response.method || ajax.method;
    var effect = ajax.getEffect(response);

    // We don't know what response.data contains: it might be a string of text
    // without HTML, so don't rely on jQuery correctly iterpreting
    // $(response.data) as new HTML rather than a CSS selector. Also, if
    // response.data contains top-level text nodes, they get lost with either
    // $(response.data) or $('<div></div>').replaceWith(response.data).
    var new_content_wrapped = $('<div></div>').html(response.data);
    var new_content = new_content_wrapped.contents();

    // For legacy reasons, the effects processing code assumes that new_content
    // consists of a single top-level element. Also, it has not been
    // sufficiently tested whether attachBehaviors() can be successfully called
    // with a context object that includes top-level text nodes. However, to
    // give developers full control of the HTML appearing in the page, and to
    // enable Ajax content to be inserted in places where DIV elements are not
    // allowed (e.g., within TABLE, TR, and SPAN parents), we check if the new
    // content satisfies the requirement of a single top-level element, and
    // only use the container DIV created above when it doesn't. For more
    // information, please see http://drupal.org/node/736066.
    if (new_content.length != 1 || new_content.get(0).nodeType != 1) {
      new_content = new_content_wrapped;
    }
    // If removing content from the wrapper, detach behaviors first.
    var settings = response.settings || ajax.settings || Drupal.settings;
    Drupal.detachBehaviors(wrapper, settings);
    if ($.waypoints != undefined) {
      $.waypoints('refresh');
    }

    // Set up our default query options. This is for advance users that might
    // change there views layout classes. This allows them to write there own
    // jquery selector to replace the content with.
    var content_query = response.options.content || '.view-content';

    // If we're using any effects. Hide the new content before adding it to the DOM.
    if (effect.showEffect != 'show') {
      new_content.find(content_query).children().hide();
    }

    // Add the new content to the page.
    wrapper.find('.pager a').remove();
    wrapper.find('.pager').parent('.item-list').html(new_content.find('.pager'));
    wrapper.find(content_query)[method](new_content.find(content_query).children());
    if (effect.showEffect != 'show') {
      wrapper.find(content_query).children(':not(:visible)')[effect.showEffect](effect.showSpeed);
    }

    // Attach all JavaScript behaviors to the new content
    // Remove the Jquery once Class, TODO: There needs to be a better
    // way of doing this, look at .removeOnce() :-/
    var classes = wrapper.attr('class');
    var onceClass = classes.match(/jquery-once-[0-9]*-[a-z]*/);
    wrapper.removeClass(onceClass[0]);
    var settings = response.settings || ajax.settings || Drupal.settings;
    Drupal.attachBehaviors(wrapper, settings);
  }

  /**
   * Attaches the AJAX behavior to Views Load More waypoint support.
   */
  Drupal.behaviors.ViewsLoadMore = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      if (settings && settings.viewsLoadMore && settings.views.ajaxViews) {
        opts = {
          offset: '100%'
        };
        $.each(settings.viewsLoadMore, function(i, setting) {
          var view = '.view-id-' + setting.view_name + '.view-display-id-' + setting.view_display_id + ' .pager-next a';
          $(view).waypoint(function(event, direction) {
            $(view).waypoint('remove');
            $(view).click();
          }, opts);
        });
      }
    },
    detach: function (context, settings, trigger) {
      if (settings && Drupal.settings.viewsLoadMore && settings.views.ajaxViews) {
        $.each(settings.viewsLoadMore, function(i, setting) {
          var view = '.view-id-' + setting.view_name + '.view-display-id-' + setting.view_display_id + ' .pager-next a';
          $(view, context).waypoint('destroy');
        });
      }
    }
     };
})(jQuery);
```

How do i solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update your jQuery to 1.7.1 or 1.7.2 and use $.on() instead of $.hover() - with $.on(), you're basically giving it a "live" handler without the need to attach the handler individually to each element. Use your primary container as the attach selector, and your .thumb and .thumb img selectors as your trigger selectors, like so:

```
$('#main').on('hover', '.thumb', function() {
    // do your hover stuff
}
```

$.on attaches to an EXISTING permanent DOM element and listens for the event to be triggered on a child element matching the supplied selector. Attaching any event listener to an object that isn't present on the page at the time of the page's rendering will not work. And .live() is deprecated in jQuery 1.7.x.

Comment: Can you give me a sample on jsfiddle please?